# Magento 2.3 not sending emails to the same domain as the sender

Tags: magento2, email

In my Magento stores, I have set the default email address for sending email as for e.g info@alias.com. Every customer is receiving emails from info@alias.com
But if the customer has the email address with the same domain as ours for e.g team@alias.com it does not receive any email.
In short any email with the domain alias.com does not receive an email from info@alias.com
what can be the issue? Is it because of the same domain name or something else, how can I resolve this

Comment: Do you have email server on the same server ?
If no its may be due to its searching mail account on your web server

Answer (score 2):

**I’ve seen this happen a couple of times this week, so I thought I’d briefly write about it.**

**A Magento storefront is taking orders, but the emails aren’t coming into the the company’s corporate email system.**

Usually it’s an Exchange account, but not always.

Email gets through to a Yahoo email address or a Gmail account, but not to a corporate email account, or to their customers who are placing orders on the Magento Enterprise or Magento Community site.

**If this is happening to you, here’s where to start the troubleshooting process:**

**1. Make sure that the email that you are sending from is from the same domain that the Website is using.** For example, if your Magento site was www.[domainname].com, you’d want to make sure that the email addresses for the store are something@[domainname].com.

**2. Make sure that your Website actually has permission to send out emails on behalf of your domain.** This gets into the DNS zone file of A records, SPF records and more. But when your Magento site tries to send email to another server, that other server does a number of checks. Does your site have an SPF record? If so (and it’s set up properly to allow the A record), your email will get through.

**3. Finally, make sure that your site’s Reverse IP address is set properly.** I just looked at (and fixed) a Website where the Reverse IP was not set up. It was just like when you receive a phone call, and the Caller ID is blank. (If you’re like me, you’re not likely to answer the phone.) Set the Reverse IP to your domain name (without the www). If you don’t have control over the Reverse IP address, find out what that name is (it may be random, or related to the hosting company) and add that in as an allowed domain under the SPF record.

**That should help!**

But if you need help, [domainname]’s team of Magento DNS experts can help troubleshoot this for you.  Our founder, Jeff Finkelstein, is a DNS Zone file guru, and can usually troubleshoot and fix issues like this quickly.